# Unattended install of PostgreSQL 9.5 on Windows, modifying config files

Tags: windows, installation, postgresql, automated-install, unattended

I'd like to perform an unattended installation of PostgreSQL 9.5 on a number of Windows 7 machines, ideally by assigning an MSI via Group Policy. There seems to be no MSI file, but the EnterpriseDB EXE installer supports "--mode unattended". That should be workable, but I also want to change some options in postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf (to enable SSPI authentication, for example). What's the easiest way to do this? Is there a way I can edit the files inside the installer EXE, for example? (7-zip fails to extract it.) Or do I have to write my own script to modify the config files and restart the service afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a [Configuration Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software) tool, like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) or [Rex](https://www.rexify.org/) to connect to the machines (via SSH) after the install and update the config files.

This allows you to manage changes better in the future, and keep the configs in source control.